# spark-submit - could not parse master url

Tags: apache-spark

I am getting error while executing spark job using spark-submit on windows 10 machine. The command is:

```
c:\workspaces\Spark2Demo>spark-submit --class retail_db.GetRevenuePerOrder  --master local .\target\scala-2.12\spark2demo_2.12-0.1.jar c:\workspaces\data\retail_db\orders\part-00000 c:\workspaces\output
```

The error I get is:

```
2019-03-12 19:09:33 ERROR SparkContext:91 - Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'c:\workspaces\data\retail_db\orders\part-00000'
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2784)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:493)
        at retail_db.GetRevenuePerOrder$.main(GetRevenuePerOrder.scala:7)
        at retail_db.GetRevenuePerOrder.main(GetRevenuePerOrder.scala)
```

The file exists and is accessible. I am able to run the program in IDE. Following is the prorgram:

```
package retail_db
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf,SparkContext}

object GetRevenuePerOrder {
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(args(0)).setAppName("GetRevenuePerOrder")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    sc.setLogLevel("DEBUG")
    println(args)
    val orderItems = sc.textFile(args(1))
    val revenuePerOrder = orderItems.map(oi => (oi.split(",")(1).toInt, oi.split(",")(4).toFloat)).reduceByKey(_ + _).map(oi => (oi._1 + "," + oi._2))
    revenuePerOrder.saveAsTextFile(args(2))
  }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: master-url is not a file, but an url to the master resource manager (for distributed systems). https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls

Comment: why is the execution complaining about invalid master url. I have given master as local.

Comment: val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(args(0)). Here you are resetting the master url.

Comment: Thanks Apurba. That fixes the issue. Please add this as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting Master twice. First time in the spark-submit command (--master local), where you are setting it as local and the second time in the SparkConf (new SparkConf().setMaster(args(0))). As mentioned in the [spark configuration page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), "Properties set directly on the SparkConf take highest precedence, then flags passed to spark-submit or spark-shell, then options in the spark-defaults.conf file", the local master set by the spark-submit, gets overwritten by the SparkConf argument. Please remove the second part.